# Dynamic bulkinsert of mutiple csv files from different location folders

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have multiple csv files in different location folders. I want to do bulk-insert in SQL server dynamically which will do bulk insert in a single table. 
I did it for a single CSV file. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. You can read up on `xp_dirtree` and `cursors` to see how they work. If your files are spread across different parent folders, or different drives, you'll need an additional cursor to go get them...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Set some variables
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @fileLocation VARCHAR(128) = '\\server\e$\data\'                        --location of files (parent folder)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)                                                     --dynamic sql variable
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(128)                                                  --full file name variable if you want to use this


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Get a list of all the file names in the directory
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FileNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FileNames
CREATE TABLE #FileNames (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
    ,depth int
    ,isfile bit)
INSERT #FileNames (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC xp_dirtree @fileLocation, 1, 1


--Here's all the files and folders. Note isFile field.
select * from #FileNames


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Create a cursor to fetch the file names
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
select name from #FileNames where isfile = 1

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @fileName

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--For each file, bulk insert to the proper view, update the proper table, update the log, etc...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --do your bulk insert work
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @fileName
    END
```